# I was banned from asking questions again

Tags: discussion, quality-control, inquiry

I agree that my questions were not that good, but I learnt from my mistakes.

I've been banned for a long time now and I'm not seeing any hopes of being unbanned.

Shouldn't I get a 2nd chance?

Answer (score 5):

I think you were automatically banned by SE for asking poorly received/low-quality questions. Moderators cannot lift automatic bans. Yow will only be able to ask a question after six months of your last question. If that question is received positively, you may be able to ask further questions. Meanwhile, you can fix your existing posts which may help you to reduce your ban.

[Everything you want to know about automatic bans can be understood from this link.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Answer (score 5):

The answer can be found in the help center, see [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) entry.
In short: You are a new user which asked too many bad questions (downvoted and/or closed), which brings up this ban by the system. As this happens automatically, we cannot do anything about it. Read the instructions in the link above, which may help.